# \label does not work

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

am looking help for two things. (1) I would like to write the text as 'In Fig. (1) and in Fig. (2a)', for which the TEX is written as follows:

```
Shown in Fig. (\ref{fig:main}) and shown in Fig. (\ref{fig:2})'

\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
\label{fig:main} \caption{main}

  \subfloat[ 1]{\label{fig:1}\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{11}}
  \subfloat[ 2]{\label{fig:2}\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{22}}
  \subfloat[ 3]{\label{fig:3}\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{33}}
  \subfloat[ 4]{\label{fig:4}\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{44}}

  \subfloat[ 5]{\label{fig:5}\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{55}}
  \subfloat[ 6]{\label{fig:6}\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{66}}
  \subfloat[ 7]{\label{fig:7}\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{77}}
  \subfloat[ 8]{\label{fig:8}\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{88}}

\end{figure*}
```

But the output does not link to **Fig. (2a)**.

(2) Also, with this code the captions are above the image, how can we move them below the image, something like this:

```
    11      22      33      44
(a) 1   (b) 2   (c) 3   (d) 4
          Fig. (1) main
```

where, 11, 22, ...so on are the images.

Packages used:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

Any solution? Or Any other way of working on it, where labels for individual images can also be referred? Thank you.

Comment: In floats `\label` must always be **after** `\caption`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, I tried that but does not work. Deleting .log file too does not help.

Comment: You're using the syntax for the package `subfig`, while you load `subcaption`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside floats, always place `\label` after `\caption` (in the figure you had them the other way round). Since you are using `\ref{fig:2}` which has the string used to label the second subfigure, you are hyperlinking to the second subfigure, not to the first one; to hyperlink the first subfigure you need `\ref{fig:1}` (by the way, try to pick more describtive strings for your references).

Use

```
\captionsetup[subfloat]{position=bottom}
```

to have the subcaptions below the subfigures.

I added some `\hfill`s to give some spacing between the subfigures:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\captionsetup[subfloat]{position=bottom}

\begin{document}
Shown in Fig.~(\ref{fig:main}) and shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:2}
\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
\caption{main}\label{fig:main}
  \subfloat[ 1]{\label{fig:1}\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{11}}\hfill
  \subfloat[ 2\label{fig:2}]{\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{22}}\hfill
  \subfloat[ 3]{\label{fig:3}\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{33}}\hfill
  \subfloat[ 4]{\label{fig:4}\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{44}}

  \subfloat[ 5]{\label{fig:5}\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{55}}\hfill
  \subfloat[ 6]{\label{fig:6}\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{66}}\hfill
  \subfloat[ 7]{\label{fig:7}\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{77}}\hfill
  \subfloat[ 8]{\label{fig:8}\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{88}}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would even say _inside_ the caption's argument (`\caption{\label{…}main}`).